# Нужно ли перезапускать cron после добавления скрипта?

Tags: linux, debian, cron

Добавил скрипт в cron.daily. Нужно ли после этого как то перезапустить крон что бы он подтянул этот скрипт. Прошло 2 дня, а скрипт судя по всему не отработал.

Comment: нет, **пере**запускать не нужно

Comment: почему вы думаете, что он не отработал? посмотрите syslog

Comment: для проверки был создан скрипт который в домашнем каталоге создаёт файл. Файл не создался

Comment: А скрипт от какого пользователя запустился? Вам бы документацию почитать на crontab, там описано как запустить пользовательский вариант.

Comment: После каждого добавления делаю service crond reload, проблем не возникало.